# ExtJS ComboBox Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, combobox, extjs4

my Ext version is 4.07.

I create a ComboBox and want to store data from a JSON file.

```
var Combo = Ext.create(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
                editable: false,
                fieldLabel: 'Choose Format',
                store: Ext.create(Ext.data.Store, {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    fields: ['format', 'dimension'],
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: 'jsonurl', // has masked here
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'formats'
                        }
                    },
                    listeners: {
                      load: function(me) {
                        var defaultValue = me.getAt(0).data.dimension;
                        Combo.select(defaultValue);
                      }
                  }
                }),
                displayField: 'dimension',
                valueField: 'format',
                queryMode: 'local',
            });
```

In this case, it did the ajax call and loaded the data but when I click the combobox the Chrome developer tool console show an error message: 
"**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null**"

In firefox console show this message: 
"**TypeError: Ext.fly(...) is null
Ext.fly(child, '_scrollChildIntoView').scrollIntoView(this, hscroll);**"

Is there any ideas to fix the problem?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**

I got the problem. I wrote a load event and want to set default value to the combobox but I set incorrect reference cause this error message.

```
load: function(me) {
  //var defaultValue = me.getAt(0).data.dimension; //incorrect
  var defaultValue = me.getAt(0); //correct
  preferFormat.select(defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Can you showcase it in a fiddle on fiddle.sencha.com ?

Comment: I tried to rebuild environment on Sencha fiddle but I can't fetch JSON file with mock data in Ext 4.0.7.[sencha fiddle](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?304559-mock-data-404-not-found)

Comment: In this case, It works fine in Ext 4.2.1. Maybe it is the framework problem.

Comment: Early Ext JS 4 versions were buggy. Better use the latest 4 which is 4.2.3.